# Php get how many days and hours left from a date

Tags: php, date, laravel-5.7

I have a created_at date saved liked this "2011-09-23 19:10:18" And I want to get the days and hours left 
until the date is reached. How do I do that? and column name in database remain days automatically update daily with remain days, please solve this

Answer (score 30, accepted):

PHP fragment:

```
<?php

//Convert to date
$datestr="2011-09-23 19:10:18";//Your date
$date=strtotime($datestr);//Converted to a PHP date (a second count)

//Calculate difference
$diff=$date-time();//time returns current time in seconds
$days=floor($diff/(60*60*24));//seconds/minute*minutes/hour*hours/day)
$hours=round(($diff-$days*60*60*24)/(60*60));

//Report
echo "$days days $hours hours remain<br />";
?>
```

Note the hour-round and no minutes/seconds consideration means it can be slightly inaccurate.

Comment: this one should answer the question asked. thanks, helped me as well

Comment: So is there possibility of having minutes left or not ??

Comment: @SenTisso yes.  Switch the `$hours` to use `floor` instead of `round`, subtract the `$hours` off the `$diff` (like with `$days` to find `$hours`), divide the resulting amount by 60 and round (to get minutes)

    /*...*/$secondsPerHour=60*60;
    $secondsPerDay=60*60*24;
    $days=floor($diff/$secondsPerDay);
    $diff-=$days*$secondsPerDay;
    $hours=floor($diff/$secondsPerHour);
    $diff-=$hours*$secondsPerHour;
    $minutes=round($diff/60);

Answer (score 22):

This should seed your endeavor.

```
getdate(strtotime("2011-09-23 19:10:18"))
```

Full conversion:

```
$seconds = strtotime("2011-09-23 19:10:18") - time();

$days = floor($seconds / 86400);
$seconds %= 86400;

$hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
$seconds %= 3600;

$minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
$seconds %= 60;


echo "$days days and $hours hours and $minutes minutes and $seconds seconds";
```

Answer (score 21):

as of PHP 5.3.0 you could use build-in Date object:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: I was just wondering what params I can use. Here's the answer: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#refsect1-dateinterval.format-parameters

Answer (score 1):

it would be something like

```
echo $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");echo "\n";

$original=time($date);


$modified = "2011-09-23 19:10:18";

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$modified);echo "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is improved answer from CountZero. I used this solution for counter for time remaining before expiration of offer. Addition to first three lines of CountZero code:

```
$days = $interval->d;
$hours = $interval->h;
$minutes = $interval->i;
$seconds = $interval->s;
```

And now, you can use string functions to moderate your return values, to merge all or add '0' or '00' in front of the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can find current date and time using date() function and then subtract

$x = 2011-09-23 - current_date

this will give you no. of days left.

Do same with time as well ..

Hope this helps