# Calculating the amount of time between the two timestamps

Tags: php, xml

XML File;

```
 <programme channel="cnn.info" start="20131027060000" stop="20131027061500">
 <title>hello CONTENT</title>
 <premiere/></programme>
```

"Start" & "stop" (in xml) should be done to calculate the time difference between clocks?

For example:

```
Title: hello.. 
Time:left 24 minutes
```

xml file with the data in the calculation of the time, how can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Should be aiming for something like this:

```
$string = <<<XML
 <programme channel="cnn.info" start="20131027060000" stop="20131027061500">
 <title>hello CONTENT</title>
 <premiere/></programme>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

$start = $xml->attributes()->start;
$stop = $xml->attributes()->stop;
$title = $xml->title;
$datetime1 = new DateTime($start);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($stop);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo "Title: " . $title . "\n";
echo $interval->format('Time left: %i minutes');
```

Output:

```
Title: hello CONTENT
Time left: 15 minutes
```

http://3v4l.org/gDPTQ

Comment: PHP is not in the XML data file.. XML File is here: http://tvprofil.net/xmltv/data/cnn.info/weekly_cnn.info_tvprofil.net.xml

Comment: Then you'd use simplexml_load_file instead of the string...

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("filename.xml");

echo $xml->programme->title . "<br />";
echo "Time: left" . $time_left;
```

`$time_left` will be the stop date minus the start date, then convert it to a php date.

Also read this topic:
[Php get how many days and hours left from a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474762/php-get-how-many-days-and-hours-left-from-a-date)