# PHP How many days old is this date?

Tags: php, date

Im trying to work out how many days old is a date in my database.

For example with this date:

```
$postdate = '2013-12-19';
```

I want it to work out that it is 1 day old. If it is todays date then it should be 0.

How can i do this in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of [Php get how many days and hours left from a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474762/php-get-how-many-days-and-hours-left-from-a-date?rq=1)

Comment: This question should be closed because it has been asked so many many times before and answered so many many times before; and a user who has been a member for as long as this should know how to find those answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = new \DateTime('2013-12-19');
$b = new \DateTime;

echo $a->diff($b)->days; // => 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
try {
    $db_date = new DateTime($postdate);
    $today = new DateTime();
    $interval = $db_date->diff($today);
    echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$postdate = '2013-12-20';
$today = date('Y-m-d'); // today date
$diff = strtotime($today) - strtotime($postdate);
echo $days = (int)$diff/(60*60*24);
```