# Sum of hours and minutes from date or milliseconds

Tags: php

Let`s say we have the time in milliseconds like this, and we want the get the sum of the 3 hours ( 02:00 + 03:00 + 01:30 = 06:30).

```
1388361603000 equals with Mon Dec 30 2013 02:00:03 GMT+0200
1388365202000 equals with Mon Dec 30 2013 03:00:02 GMT+0200
1388359845000 equals with Mon Dec 30 2013 01:30:45 GMT+0200
```

If i get the sum of those 3 i get :

```
4165086650000 equals with Tue Dec 27 2101 02:30:50 GMT+0200
```

If i get the sum divided by 1000 ( to get the seconds ) the result is this :

```
4165086650 equals with Wed Feb 18 1970 06:58:06 GMT+0200
```

Tried like this also and didnt worked :

```
$time1 = date("H:i", 1388361603000 / 1000);
$time2 = date("H:i", 1388365202000 / 1000);
$time3 = date("H:i", 1388359845000 / 1000);
$total_time = $time1 + $time2 + $time3;
```

The result was 6, if i remove the : between H and i the result will be 630 ( which still is not good ).

Something that i did and worked was this :

```
$hours1 = date("H", 1388361603000 / 1000);
$minutes1 = date("i", 1388361603000 / 1000);
$hours2 = date("H", 1388365202000 / 1000);
$minutes2 = date("i", 1388365202000 / 1000);
$hours3 = date("H", 1388359845000 / 1000);
$minutes3 = date("i", 1388359845000 / 1000);

$date = ($hours1 + $hours2 + $hours3) . ":" . ($minutes1 + $minutes2 + $minutes3);
$milliseconds = strtotime($date) * 1000;
```

echo $date = 6:30

echo $milliseconds = 1388377800000 which equals with Mon Dec 30 2013 06:30:00 GMT+0200

If i get hours bigger then 24 or minutes bigger then 60, i must convert it proper hours and minutes.

Is this the correct way of doing it or there is another simple way ?

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit or a 64-bit system?

Comment: strtotime() maybe a better option

Comment: 64 system, but i dont think it matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple way I can imagine

```
echo "Time is: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now +3 hours"));
```

You can also feed strtotime() a UNIX timestamp as second param.

Comment: tried date("H:i", strtotime("00:00 +" .$hours . "hours + " . $minutes . "minutes") and it works, but also if i have hours total more than 24 then time goes from 0. But i can fix this in another way. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474762/php-get-how-many-days-and-hours-left-from-a-date might help you. Basically, just break hours into days and hours.. etc.