# Convert End date to days, hours, minutes, seconds remaning

Tags: php, date, echo

I've tried looking around the web but didn't find enough info to convert end date field into time remaining.

Right now I have this code:

```
echo '
<tr>
   <td style="background: #f0f0f0;" width=50% align=center>'.$row['end_date'].'</td>
</tr>';
```

which shows a value end_date from sql. However, I need to use Time left instead, so to convert it into x days x hours x minutes x seconds left.
The date itself looks like this: 2017-02-08 20:52:20

Could anyone help me out, please?

Comment: Your question appears to have nothing to do with SQL so I removed that tag.

Comment: What have you tried thus far in formatting the date as you desire it?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: have you tried TIMEDIFF()?

Comment: I've tried this tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474762/php-get-how-many-days-and-hours-left-from-a-date but it provides only daysa nd hours, no minutes and seconds. Also whenever I tried inserting the echo inside the <td> website gave me 500 error.

Comment: I haven't tried TIMEDIFF(). Thank you for suggestion. Going to try it now.

Comment: <td style="background: #f0f0f0; color: #ff0000;" width=50% align=center>'.TIMEDIFF("$row['full_address']","NOW()").'</td> gave me 500 error...

Comment: You need to take the code in the duplicate question and expand upon it. Just because it is slightly different doesn't mean it isn't useful. If you have any problems, post the code you wrote and what error you get and then we can try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('now');
$datetime2 = date_create($row['end_date']);
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo '
<tr>
<td style="background: #f0f0f0" width=50% align=center>'.$interval->format('%a days %h hours %i min %s sec').'</td>
</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [date/time](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) functions, especially [`date_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). The example on that page does what you're looking for, I think.